# Locally connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ $X$ is locally connected if and only if the components of each open subset of $X$ are open.

I have a question in the next proof.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Suppose that $X$ is locally connected. Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$, and $C$ be a component of $U$. If $x \in C$, then there is a connected open set $V \subseteq X$ such that $x \in V \subseteq  U$, by our hypothesis. Since $C$ is a component of $x$ in $U$ and $V$ is a connected subset of $U$ containing $x$, we have $V \subseteq C$. Thus $C$ is a neighbourhood of each of its points, and
therefore open.

My question is in the part where they state that $V \subseteq C$.

I know that if we have a topological space $X$ and $Y \subseteq X$ connected (in $X$), then $Y \subseteq C$ where $C$ is a component of $X$.

Now, in the proof we have $V \subseteq U$ and $V$ connected in $X$. 
We would have to prove that $V$ is connected in $U$ and then we have $V \subseteq C$ because $x \in C$.

In the proof they do not mention any of this, they simply say that $V$ is a connected (in $X$) subset of $U$. This condition implies that $V$ is connected in $U$?

the connectedness of subsets of a subspace confuse me.

Answer (score 1):

If $A \subseteq X$ is a subspace there is no notion of $A$ being "connected in $X$". Just that $A$ is connected as a space (i.e. it has no non-trivial clopen set). Of course, $A$ does have the subspace topology wrt $X$, but for connectedness (and compactness and local connectedness etc.) we should just judge $A$ as a space on its own.

If $U$ is open, $C$ is a component of $U$ (as its own space), $x \in C$: As $X$ is locally connected, we know there is a connected neighbourhood $V_x$ of $x$ that is a subset of $U$ (this uses two things: $U$ is open in $X$ and the connected neighbourhoods form a local base at $x$ in $X$).

So $V_x$ is connected, it is a subset of $U$ and contains $x$. So looking inside $U$ as its own space, it's by definition that $C$, the component of $U$, obeys $V_x \subseteq C$ by maximality of the component. This shows that any $x\in C$ is an interior point (in $U$, just as in $X$) of $C$, so $C$ is open.

Comment: When I was referring to "connected in $U$" I was obviously referring to seeing the total space as $U$ with the subspace topology inherited from $X$.  
However, I have a question. The components of $U$ are the maximum connected sets (seeing $U$ as the total space), 
So if we want to see that $V_x$ is contained in some component we would have to see first that it is connected as a subspace of $U$. If $U$ not is open, this falls.

Comment: @Norman the openness allows us to find $V_x$ (a connected neighbourhood) to be inside $U$ in the first place from the local connectedness of $X$. Then we can use $V_x$ in the connectedness/component argmument *because* it lies in $U$. $V_x$ is connected if we see it in its own subspace topology, or equivalently as subspace of $U$ or $X$...

Answer (score 0):

$U$ is open, so open sets in $U$ in the subspace topology are precisely those open sets in $X$ which are contained in $U$. It follows that for a subspace of $U$, being connected in $U$ vs. in $X$ are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, if $U$ isn't Open?

Comment: @Norman If $U$ isn't open that fails.

Comment: For general $U \subset X$, it is always true that $V \subset U$ being connected in $U$ implies it is connected in $X$ (a separation of $V$ in $X$ gives a separation in $U$ by intersecting with $U$).

The converse is not true in general, but the counterexamples are a bit weird; you would need open-in-$U$ sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ covering $V$, such that any open-in-$X$ sets $\tilde U_1$ and $\tilde U_2$ containing them must intersect each other.

Comment: @NathanielMayer There is no notion of "connected in $X$". Just connectedness of a space and the subspace topology to make all subsets their own space. Connectedness, like compactness, is inherently "absolute" in that way.

Comment: Sure, but let a space $X$ and $V \subset U \subset X$ . If $V$ is connected (with the subspace topology inherited from $X$) is true that $V$ is connected (with the subspace topology inherited from $U$) ? Note that $U$ is not open. That would be my question, perhaps better written.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686825/about-the-connected, I question this , maybe we helpful.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, you're right. I could swear that I've heard that terminology used to describe the notion I used in my comment (there is such a notion, as I articulated), but I was misinterpreting the original post to think that was relevant here. Norman, please disregard my previous comment.